# Minify CSS and JS for Magento

Tags: javascript, css, magento-1.9, minify

I have an issue with minifying CSS and Javascript for Magento. Our website now is 1.1 MB large and we want to reduce it to 1 MB (or less than that if it is possible). I used the function "CSS Settings"/"Javascript Settings" in Magento but it effect one of our extensions so I have to unable them. I am wondering is there any other way to minify the CSS/Js by coding or something like that as I do not want to use extension for this matter. I am keen to find another method that can speed up our site because it could help us rank better in Google Search battle. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can  minify CSS and Javascript online. Have you tried it ? If not please visit these links - :)

[CSS MINIFIER](https://cssminifier.com/)
[JAVASCRIPT MINIFIER](https://javascript-minifier.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice Harwinder Signh. The issue is that we have more than 32 js along with 19 css to load every now and then. So this method seems a bit consuming time as I need to manually do this one by one. Do you have any other way to make this faster. Cheers.

Comment: @WillTruong [PLEASE CLICK HERE](https://github.com/mrclay/minify) Hope! It could help you. :)